# How many adhans are there for Friday prayer?

Tags: salat, adhan

I've heard brother's say that there's two,  and yet other mosques only have the one.

I've also noticed, there's mosques where they have two,  *everyone* performs the Sunnah prayer at the same time. Is this a differing between Madahabs?

So how many adhans should there be,  according to scholars?

Comment: The sunna of the prophet (pbuh) was two adhans one of them (the last) in front of the Imam. I think later during the time of the 4 Caliphs a 3rd adhan has been held. In my fathers home town there also have been an extra adhan at doha time to recall people that it is Friday (as it was the case in Ramadan during the time of the prophet to let people prepare themselves before fajr prayer). But this may fall under local customs.

Comment: After a certain research i have to correct myself: Your concern isn't easy to answer: As we have many issues deep inside: What is the definition of one Adhan (one adhan by one mu'adhin/mu'ezzin or many mu'adhins? if many is this allowed for jumuah or other prayers?). What is the meaning of the three adhans at the time of 'Othman mentioned in the sahih hadith (scholars say the 3rd is the Iqamah, while some take it literally). Should there be a pose between each adhan (how long should it be?) and is the 2nd/3rd adhan still relevant nowadays? ...

Comment: In Surah al-Jummah, Allah speaks about one adhan.

Comment: @Sayyid i do agree with you, but the verse could be interpreted, as: this nida' (adhan) is the one for the prayer itself (which in my opinion would be a weak interpretation) or the real adhan (the one before the Imam stands up to hold the khutba)! So this would be an explication which goes ahead with my research and interpreted the Verse http://legacy.quran.com/62/9.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your locality. For example at my masjid, our view is that the Khutbah should be given in Arabic (because it's better to do so). So coincidentally we have an English lecture or bayaan given before, then have the 1st adhaan. Thereafter we have sunnas. Then the 2nd adhaan. The imam then gives the khutbah in arabic and proceeds to lead the jumuah prayer after the iqaamah.
Generally there is 2 adhaans given.

Comment: Salam and welcome on Islam SE. Please consider taking our [tour], visiting our [help] and read [answer] to learn more about the SE model and how we expect answers to look like.

Comment: This also happens at some of the masjid where I live but not at others.  This is why I would like a definitive answer and not just someone's experience.  JazakAllah.

Answer (score -2):

The prophet's sunnah is one azan.

During the life time of prophet Muhammad there was one azan and during the rule of Hazarath Abu Bakr it was one azan. Hazarath Umar changed it to two azans.

Comment: It was Uthman and not Umar ([Saheeh Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/11/40)). Also see [islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/148205) and [islamweb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=86806)